# The other phrase of ‘happily’

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

I want to express I dance and the dance is showing someone else’ happiness instead of ‘I dance happily.’ So does ‘I dance in **his** happy way’ sound natural to native English speakers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, "I dance in his happy way" is not a natural way to phrase it.  What you are saying with "I dance in his happy way" is that *his* method of dancing is happy and you are imitating it.

A more natural way to say what you want would be **I dance happily for him** or **I dance with happiness for him**.